# Tem como fazer uma operação + ou - o valor numa query MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Exemplo:

```
select quantidade from tabela where quantidade é mais ou menos = '5';
```

Alguém conhece alguma maneira de fazer isso no MySQL? Tenho um valor aproximado a 5 e gostaria de trazê-lo do banco em uma query, só que eu não conheço nenhuma função em SQL nem nenhum jeito de fazer a condição que eu quero como no exemplo.

Comment: Defina o que é "mais ou menos".

Comment: Você pode usar o, maior que, maior igual, menor que, menor igual ... mais ou menos e tanto faz não tem. Tente explicar melhor onde isso é aplicado

Comment: Um valor que poder ser mais que 5 e menos que 5 não seria qualquer valor? Oo

Comment: Quer saber se é diferente de 5?

Answer (score 6):

Usando o `ABS`, fica bem simples:

```
SELECT campos FROM tabela WHERE ABS( valor - 5 ) < .5
                                             │      │
                          valor buscado 5 ───┘      │
  tolerancia 0,5 por exemplo (ajuste como quiser) ──┘
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6bf4/1)**.

O `ABS( )` retorna o valor sempre positivo, então o que está depois do `<` serve para ajustar a tolerância tanto para mais ou para menos.

Comment: Muito mais elegante que a minha resposta. Have an upvote good sir.

Answer (score 5):

A lógica do "marromeno" pode ser feita com uma variável auxiliar de variação.

```
DECLARE @marromeno DECIMAL(0,2)
DECLARE @eixoDaGrampola DECIMAL(2,2)

-- atribua valores aqui

SELECT
    *
FROM
    inmetro
WHERE
    valor BETWEEN (@eixoDaGrampola - @marromeno) and (@eixoDaGrampola + @marromeno)
```

Por exemplo, se sua variação for de 0,2 pra mais ou pra menos... Se você der os valores de 5 para [`@eixoDaGrampola`](http://www.onordeste.com/onordeste/enciclopediaNordeste/index.php?titulo=Bem+no+eixo+da+grampola&ltr=b&id_perso=4402) e 0.2 para `@marromeno`, você obterá todos os valores entre 4.8 e 5.2.

Boa sorte.

Comment: Exatamente... tem que dar um valor de margem.

Comment: Deixei outra versão, mas a sua é uma boa solução também. +1

Comment: @Bacco a sua é mais forte pois tem [ABS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectus_abdominis_muscle)

Comment: É, se trabalhar bem com ABS o resultado é _positivo_ :)

Answer (score 0):

select quantidade from tabela where quantidade != '5';

Resolve?